# Почему не работает метод объекта, если объект создать без конструктора

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код на Python

```
class Element:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self,name,symbol,number):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.number = number

    def dump(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.symbol)
        print(self.number)

element = Element()
element.name = 'Hydro3gen'1
element.symbol = 'H'
element.number = 1

element.dump()
```

Я только учусь...

1. Нужен ли конструктор по без аргументов в классе?
2. Почему если я не пользуюсь конструктором, а вручную ставлю значения полям объекта, то dump не вызвать, а если создать объект с конструктором, куда я подставлю все те же значения, то тогда dump работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python нет полиморфизма (такого как в С++, например), поэтому в классе не может быть двух методов с одним именем. По факту второй метод `__init__` просто перезапишет первый, и при попытке создания объекта без параметров интерпретатор выдаст ошибку:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'symbol', and 'number'
```

Если нужна возможность создания объекта без параметров, можно задать значения параметров по-умолчанию:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name=None, symbol=None, number=None):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.number = number
```

Тогда вызов `Element()` не приведет к ошибке, и поля будут инициализированы значением `None`.

Надеюсь, по первому пункту теперь все понятно.

По второму пункту: можно использовать пример класса выше (не забыв добавить метод `dump`), и все будет работать. А можно вообще создать класс без `__init__`, но с методом `dump`, инициализировать класс "снаружи", а потом вызвать `dump`, и это сработает:

```
class Element:
    def dump(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.symbol)
        print(self.number)

element = Element()
element.name = 'Hydro3gen'
element.symbol = 'H'
element.number = 1

element.dump()
```

Вывод:

```
Hydro3gen
H
1
```

Как видите, никаких ограничений на инициализацию объекта "снаружи" нет.